# Map like for like using Unity IoC

Tags: unity-container

Is there a quick way to map an ISomething to Something without doing so explicitly for every map?

So, instead of writing many of these:

```
container.RegisterType<ISomethinmg, Somethinmg>();
container.RegisterType<ISomethinmgElse, SomethinmgElse>();
```

Can I skip the registration, and just map them proper at runtime?

Comment: Google for "Unity Auto-Registration" or "unity batch registration".

Comment: see [Registration by Convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn507479(v=pandp.30))